# Laravel modal hidden value to call route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a modal with a hidden field of my current id that I need.

I need to click a button in my modal to confirm if I should delete a user. I setup a form not sure if this is the best option and in javascript set the attr of form to the route but the route isn’t finding the correct path although in the URL it says it correctly what am I missing maybe the route should be in PHP instead of JS?

```
<div class="modal" id="mdelete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="moddelete">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="moddelete">Confirm Delete</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="POST" id="formdelete">
          <input type="hidden" name="txtid" id="txtid" />
          <input type="text" name="uid" id="uid" />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
          <span class="text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btndelete">Yes</button>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('users.show', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Show</a>
    <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-info text-white mx-2">Edit</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-2" data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#mdelete" data-id="{{$user->id}}" 
            data-name="{{$user->username}}">Delete</button>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mdelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var userid = button.data('id');
        var uname = button.data('name');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('#txtid').val(userid);
        modal.find('#uid').val(userid);
        modal.find('.modal-body').text('Are you sure you want to delete ' + uname);
      })
      $('#formdelete').submit(function() {
        var userid = $('#txtid').val();
        $('#formdelete').attr("action", "route('$users.destroy',$user->"+ userid +")");
        $('#formdelete').submit();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to generate route will fail because you are not using templating correctly:

`$('#formdelete').attr("action", "route('$users.destroy',$user->"+ userid +")");`

You can try to have your route accept optional user field, and then generate route to it, and with js append user ID value something like so:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var form = $('#formdelete');
        var path = '{{ route("users.destroy") }}';

        $('#formdelete').submit(function(event) {
            var form = $(this);
            var userid = form.find('#txtid').val();
            $('#formdelete').attr("action", path + '/' + userid);
            $('#formdelete').submit();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```